# Getting Error " Check failed: gpu_predictor_: " when trying to use XGBoost with GPU in Python

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBoost in Python getting the error

```
    xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [09:26:06] c:\users\administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.0.0\src\gbm\gbtree.h:308: Check failed: gpu_predictor_:
```

I am using Sklearn and construction the model like

```
    model = XGBRegressor(learning_rate = 0.02,
                 n_estimators = 1000,
                    max_depth = 12,
                    tree_method='gpu_hist',
                    objective = 'reg:logistic',
                    nthread = -1,
                    silent = False)
```

It works with "hist" as tree_method on cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your GPU is not supporting CUDA which is required according to the [XG Boost website](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/):

> The GPU algorithms in XGBoost require a graphics card with compute
> capability 3.5 or higher, with CUDA toolkits 10.0 or later

At least, this was my problem. If you want to check it, you can use [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported).

Sadly, I couldn't find a workaround for this problem.